# Best practice for generic data structure implementation in C

Tags: c, data-structures, avl-tree

In my adventures implementing generic data structures in C, I've come across a dilemma. For example, in the following code:

```
void add_something(avl_tree_t * my_tree) {
        int new_element = 123;

        avl_insert(my_tree, (void*)&new_element);
}

int main() {
        avl_tree_t * my_tree = avl_create();

        add_something(my_tree);

        // do stuff

        avl_print(my_tree, function_that_prints_ints);

        exit(0);
}
```

In which `avl_insert` is defined as

```
void avl_insert(avl_tree_t * tree, void * data) {
        avl_node_t * new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct avl_node));

        new_node->data = data;
        // do tree balancing stuff
}
```

In order for my generic insertion function to work, I have to pass it a `void *` item to store. However, in order for that to work, in this case I need to pass in the address of the new `int` item I'm adding so that I can then dereference it to a `void *`. If I am not mistaken, when we're back in the `main` function, the memory address in which I stored my new element will be compromised.

One way I looked into to solve this issue is to pass in the size of the things I am storing in the tree as a parameter for `avl_create`, and then allocating memory for a copy of each element I insert. This works because you don't need the original address or value for whatever you added.

Another thing that works is only using the data structure in the span of a single function, which is obviously not viable.

My question is this: what is the best way to go about storing statically allocated data in a generic data structure, be it basic C types or user made structures?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the object has static storage duration, then it's not going anywhere, and you don't have to worry about copying it. If it has automatic storage duration, then, yes, you have to allocate and copy.

Comment: So the solution, should I face for both cases, would be to implement two different data structures for each use case? Talk about overhead. Thank you!

Comment: No, you only need to use the version that works in all cases.

Comment: How would I go about implementing a version that works in all cases? Passing some kind of value that tells the data structure whether to copy or just store the pointer?

Comment: That's one way of doing it, but it's more complex to write. In the more general case, just copy and allocate in all cases.

Comment: Either that, or never pass automatic values to be stored; allocate them dynamically outside the scope of the object and pass in the pointers.

Comment: I'll play around with defining some constants that indicate the behaviour of the data structure. Thank you very much! Feel free to post an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store pointers to data with automatic storage duration, yes, you would have to know the size of the elements in the container and allocate and copy the pointed-to data.

The simplest way is to just allocate and copy in all cases, optionally using a user-specified `clone()` or `create()` function to make deep copies, if necessary. This also entails the use of a user-specified `destroy()` function to dispose of the copies properly (again, if necessary).

To be able to avoid the allocation, then you have to have some kind of state variable that lets you know if the container should allocate, or just copy the pointer value itself.

Note that this should apply to the *container* object, not to the individual nodes or elements. If a container stores data in one way or the other, it should store all data that way. See [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

This is the more complex approach, since you have to be sure to use the correct process for adding and deleting elements based on the state variable. It's ususally much simpler to just make sure you never pass in a pointer to a value with automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

Use a mix-in style; e.g. do not make data part of the node but the node part of the data:

```
struct avl_node {
    struct avl_node *parent;
    struct avl_node *left;
    struct avl_node *right;
};

struct person {
    char const *name;
    struct avl_node node;
};

struct animal {
    struct avl_node node;
    int dangerousness;
};
```

Constructors for `animal` are like

```
struct animal *animal_create(double d)
{
    struct animal *animal = malloc(sizeof *animal);

    *animal = (struct animal) {
        .node = AVL_NODE_INIT(),
        .dangerousness = d,
    };

    return animal;
}
```

The generic AVL tree operations could look like

```
void avl_tree_insert(struct avl_node **root, struct avl_node *node, 
                     int (*cmp)(struct avl_node const *a, struct avl_node const *b))
{
    /* .... */
}
```

and a `cmp` function for `animal` like

```
int animal_cmp(struct avl_node const *a_, struct avl_node const *b_)
{
     struct animal const *a = container_of(a_, struct animal, node);
     struct animal const *b = container_of(b_, struct animal, node);

     return a->dangerousness - b->dangerousness;
}
```